# pandas calculates column value means on groups and means across whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `df`, `df['period'] = (df['date1'] - df['date2']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')`

```
code    y_m        date1        date2         period    
1000    201701    2017-12-10   2017-12-09       1
1000    201701    2017-12-14   2017-12-12       2
1000    201702    2017-12-15   2017-12-13       2
1000    201702    2017-12-17   2017-12-15       2
2000    201701    2017-12-19   2017-12-18       1
2000    201701    2017-12-12   2017-12-10       2
2000    201702    2017-12-11   2017-12-10       1
2000    201702    2017-12-13   2017-12-12       1
2000    201702    2017-12-11   2017-12-10       1
```

then `groupby` `code` and `y_m` to calculate the average of `date1-date2`,

```
df_avg_period = df.groupby(['code', 'y_m'])['period'].mean().reset_index(name='avg_period')

code        y_m        avg_period
1000        201701     1.5
1000        201702     2
2000        201701     1.5
2000        201702     1
```

but I like to convert `df_avg_period` into a matrix that transposes column `code` to rows and `y_m` to columns, like

```
      0     1     2             3              
 0   -1     0    201701       201702       
 1   0     1.44  1.44          1.4         
 2   1000  1.75  1.5           2     
 3   2000  1.20  1.5           1
```

`-1` represents a dummy value that indicates either a value doesn't exist for a specific `code`/`y_m` cell or to maintain matrix shape; 0 represents 'all' values, that averages the `code` or `y_m` or `code` and `y_m`, e.g. cell `(1,1)` averages the `period` values for all rows in `df`; `(1,2)` averages the `period` for `201701` across all rows that have this value for `y_m` in `df`.

apparently `pivot_table` cannot give correct results using `mean`. so I am wondering how to achieve that correctly?

Comment: Could you be more specific about  what you think is wrong with the results from df.pivot_table?  It seems okay to me, and your "expected" values seem wrong.

Comment: @DSM you are right, have updated op

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `pivot_table` with `margins=True`

```
piv = df.pivot_table(
    index='code', columns='y_m', values='period', aggfunc='mean', margins=True
)
# housekeeping
(piv.reset_index()
    .rename_axis(None, 1)
    .rename({'code' : -1, 'All' : 0}, axis=1)
    .sort_index(axis=1)
)

  -1         0        201701   201702
0    1000  1.750000      1.5      2.0
1    2000  1.200000      1.5      1.0
2     All  1.444444      1.5      1.4
```

Comment: was thinking using `pivot_table` on `df_avg_period` instead of `df`, which is wrong